# Extract variable name in R

Tags: r, string, function, vector, extract

In R, for a vector from a data frame:

`df$vector`

are there any functions for me to extract the vector name, preferably as a string or character like so? :

```
function(df$vector)

>"vector"
```

thanks!

Update:

to be specific, I am actually trying to build a custom function that involves returning the name of the vector input x, this is what I'm doing now :

```
function(x){
xname<-deparse(substitute(x))
cat("we are analysing",xname)
}
```

However, the vector x often comes in the form of `df$variable` and is grammatically incorrect in the `cat()` printed sentence.

thus I just wonder if there is a function for me to extract `variable` as a string from `df$variable`

Comment: `colnames(df)` could get you started

Comment: The solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71372969/extracting-vector-name-from-dfvector-in-custom-function-with-str-split-in-r/71372987#71372987

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't an answer yet, there are a few options depending on what you want. As someone mentioned above, you can get column and row names with their respective functions. I'll demonstrate with the `iris` database in R:

```
rownames(iris)
colnames(iris)
```

Which gives you this output for columns:

```
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" 
[3] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
[5] "Species"
```

And a long list of row names:

```
[1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"  
  [7] "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "12" 
 [13] "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"
```

There is also glimpse, which gives you names and details:

```
glimpse(iris)
```

This includes the types of variables, how many rows, how many columns, their values, etc:

```
Rows: 150
Columns: 5
$ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, ~
$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, ~
$ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, ~
$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, ~
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, seto~
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the `stringr` package:

You can extract the $ and everything before it with

```
.*\\$
```

And substitute it with "".

The function will be:

```
function(x) {
  xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
  return( sub(".*\\$", "", xname) )
}
```