# Extracting vector name from df$vector in custom function with str_split() in R

Tags: r, string, extract, stringr, strsplit

have been trying to programme a custom function that outputs the variable name as a string from an input object x that is a specific vector from a dataframe, i.e. in the form of df$vector , so that it function like this

```
function(iris$Species)

>"Species"
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
vector.name<-function(x){
  require(stringr)
  
  #convert df$variable into string
  xname <- as.character(deparse(substitute(x)))
  
  if (str_detect(xname,"$")==T) {
    str_split(xname,"$")
  }
}
```

but the results are unsatisfying

```
> vector.name(iris$Species)
[[1]]
[1] "iris$Species" ""
```

I have tried both `strsplit(){base}` and `str_split(){stringr}`, they both work normally for other ordinary alphabetic strings, e.g.

```
> str_split(as.character(deparse(substitute(iris$Species))),"S")
[[1]]
[1] "iris$"  "pecies"
```

How do I extract `"vector"` from `df$vector` in a custom function then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` is a metacharacter to match the end of string.  Either escape (`\\$`) or wrap it inside square bracket (`[$]`) or use `fixed` to evaluate the character literally

```
vector.name<-function(x){
 
 xname <- as.character(deparse(substitute(x)))
 if(stringr::str_detect(xname,fixed("$"))) {
    stringr::str_split(xname, fixed("$"))
  }
 
}
```

-testing

```
vector.name(iris$Species)
[[1]]
[1] "iris"    "Species"
```

---

Note that `$` in the first `str_detect` returns `TRUE` and it is just a coincidence and nothing else i.e. `$` by itself looks for the end of string and it matches in all the strings whether it is a blank or not

```
> str_detect("iris$Species", "$")
[1] TRUE
> str_detect("", "$")
[1] TRUE
```

Instead, it would be

```
> str_detect("iris$Species", "\\$")
[1] TRUE
> str_detect("", "\\$")
[1] FALSE
```

Similarly for the `str_split`, as it matches the end of the string, it returns the second element as blank

```
> str_split("iris$Species", "$")
[[1]]
[1] "iris$Species" ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution, learned a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Get <- function(x) {
       x <- deparse(substitute(x))
       gsub("^.+\\$","",x)
}

Get(iris$Species)
```

Comment: yep it works, thanks